# How To Mapping Entity When Editing it in ASP.Net MVC using AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

i have a view model like this:

```
public class CityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and an entity:

```
public class City : BaseEntity
{
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

and a BaseEntity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { set; get; }
    public string CreatedBy { set; get; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { set; get; }
    public string ModifiedBy { set; get; }
}
```

i want to map one object of type CityModel to on object of type City In Edit Action using AutoMapper ,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CityModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entity = _cityRepository.GetCity(model.Id);
        entity = model.ToEntity();
        var operationStatus = _cityRepository.Edit(entity);
        if (operationStatus.IsSuccess) operationStatus = _cityRepository.Save();

        if (operationStatus.IsSuccess)
            RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ProvinceId = new SelectList(_provinceRepository.Provinces, "Id", "Caption", model.ProvinceId);
    return View(model);
}
```

The ToEntity is :

```
public static City ToEntity(this CityModel model)
{
    return Mapper.DynamicMap<CityModel, City>(model);
}
```

and finally create map from CityModel To City Uses this Code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CityModel, City>()
              .ForMember(des => des.Caption, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Caption.ToPersianContent()))
              .ForMember(des => des.Description, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Description.ToPersianContent()));
```

when i want to map from CityModel To City , get City From Database. inherited data in city object are correct :

[image: Before Mapping]

and After Mapping , i want to keep original inherited mapping and automapper ignore mapping this base properties, but null and default values are set to this properties:

[image: After Mapping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are calling the wrong overload in "ToEntity". You have to pass in the existing entity:

```
 DynamicMap<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
```